# error en paginación de datagridview c#

Tags: c#, webforms, paginación

Estoy haciendo un servicio webform donde dependiendo de un formulario con filtros me muestra un datagridview pero en este tengo una paginación, funciona bien cuando llego al final pero cuando llego a la ultima paginacion y quiero regresar me aparece el error "El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección." ya debugee y el error me sale justo aqui.

```
  protected void gdvResultadosConsulta_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
```

//lo ocupe para ver el numero de pagina y que si lo muestre correctamente.

```
int a = gdvResultadosConsulta.PageCount;
```

//lo ocupe para ver si estaba mandando resultado y si me manda el problema es que en mi paginación en una me aparecen 5 registros y como mi paginación marca unos 35 números  y quiero regresar me manda error por que index no esta en el intervalo , yo supongo que como me marca esos 5 registros y yo quiero regresar a paginación 24 pues me dice que no existe porque solo me esta contando esos 5 porque con otras paginaciones no me marca error solo con esa .

```
 int o = gdvResultadosConsulta.Rows.Count;


           

 int lintIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow rowSelected = gdvResultadosConsulta.Rows[lintIndex];

          

  if (e.CommandName.Equals("btnConsultarDoc"))
            {}
```

En la segunda linea donde esta el rowselected.

Mi paginacion la tengo asi.

```
protected void gdvResultadosConsulta_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            txtModal.Text = "";
            gdvResultadosConsulta.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            gdvResultadosConsulta.DataSource = Session["ldsGuia"];
            gdvResultadosConsulta.DataBind();
        }
```

En el grid tengo un boton.

```
 <div class="row table-outer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gdvResultadosConsulta" class="table table-striped table-responsive" BorderWidth="1" Font-Size="10px" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gdvResultadosConsulta_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gdvResultadosConsulta_RowCommand" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="75" OnPageIndexChanging="gdvResultadosConsulta_OnPageIndexChanging">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lstrIdExpediente" HeaderText="ID DE EXPEDIENTE"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lstrNameTipoExpediente" HeaderText="TIPO DE EXPEDIENTE"></asp:BoundField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lstrEstatus" HeaderText="ESTATUS" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOCUMENTO" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnConsultarDoc" runat="server" Text="Detalles" CommandName="btnConsultarDoc" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Style="border-color: dodgerblue; color: dodgerblue;" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"></asp:Button>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <%--<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4"  FirstPageText="First"LastPageText="Last"/>--%> 
                                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="13" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="true" CssClass="GridPager" />
                                </asp:GridView>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Y mi lista la traigo aqui

```
protected void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtModal.Text = "";
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaInicial.Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaFinal.Text))
                    if (!ValidarFechas())
                        return;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGuiaMaster.Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGuiaHouse.Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRegistro.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaInicial.Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaFinal.Text))
                {
                    List<CGuia> ldsGuia = new List<CGuia>();
                    using (WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient wsInvesdoc = new WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient())
                    {
                        List<CGuia> ltblGuias = wsInvesdoc.plistObtenerGuias(txtGuiaMaster.Text.Trim(), txtGuiaHouse.Text.Trim(), txtRegistro.Text.Trim(), txtFechaInicial.Text.Trim(), txtFechaFinal.Text.Trim()).ToList();
                        if (ltblGuias.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (CGuia lvarguias in ltblGuias)
                            {
                                ldsGuia.Add(lvarguias);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pnlResultadosConsulta.Visible = false;
                            ShowAlert("No existen registros con los filtros ingresados.", "warning");
                            return;
                        }
                        wsInvesdoc.Close();
                    }

                    if (ldsGuia != null && ldsGuia.Count > 0)
                    {
                        pnlResultadosConsulta.Visible = true;
                        gdvResultadosConsulta.DataSource = ldsGuia;
                        Session["ldsGuia"] = ldsGuia;
                        gdvResultadosConsulta.DataBind();

                        if (pnlResultadosConsulta.Visible == true)
                        {
                            pnlResultadosDocumento.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
```

Y mi postback se encuentra asi.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            ShowAlert("", "");
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                txtModal.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Alguien me podria decir porque no me recupera la lista y me marca este error. De antemano gracias.